# gcc -fPIC -fPIE: difference betweenn gcc-4 and gcc-6

Tags: gcc, gcc4, gcc6

**Preamble**: this question is *not* about Oracle, instead I'd like to understand the fundamental difference between gcc-4 and gcc-6 in the handling of Position Independent Code.

So I have decided to try an Oracle 12c installation on a Debian *stretch*.

During the link stage with gcc-6, error messages like the following are issued:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/lib/libpls12.a(pci.o):
  relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.4' can not be used when making a shared object;
  recompile with -fPIC.
```

However, if I switch the compiler to use gcc-4.9, all the linking is done without any problems.

Thus my 2 questions:

- Is there a change in the defaults for -fPIC and -fPIE between gcc version 4 and 6? Most probably yes, version 6 seems to use the 2 options by default.
- More important for me: does gcc, version 6 have an option to use the version 4 behavior for the generation of position independent code? (Or will I sooner or later no more be able to link against *old* libraries because gcc-4 is no more available?)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the gcc-6 linker creates position independent executables by default. The problem can be reproduced as follows and solved by adding the linker flag -no-pie:

```
UNIX # gcc-6 -g -Wall -fno-pic -c helloworld.c -o helloworld.o

UNIX # gcc-6 -g -Wall helloworld.o -o helloworld
/usr/bin/ld: helloworld.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

UNIX # gcc-6 -g -Wall -no-pie helloworld.o -o helloworld
```

Indeed, after adding *-no-pie* to the gcc options used by Oracle, linking works without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from broeni works fine. Some additional steps I made to make it work:

During installation, I modified the default linker tool from oracle, editing the file

```
/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/db1/bin/orald
```

In the first lines, I forced to use GCC linker, and add the -no-pie option:

```
#if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" -o -n "$ORALD_USE_GCC" ] ; then
  exec gcc -no-pie "$@"
  exit 1
#fi
```

*tags: oracle 12c debian stretch*

Comment: You, sir, just made my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i know it is old post, but it is happens even in ubuntu 22.04
the solution which was working for me is to set symlink

```
sudo ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```